# SWIG Python wrappers crash on Mac OSX

Tags: python, c, macos, swig

I am trying to create a simple SWIG Python wrapper for a C function, but it always crashes with

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
```

I read that this kind of error is caused by using different versions of `python` when building/linking and when running, but as far as I can tell this is not the case here.

I downloaded, build and installed a brand new python 3.4.4. I have verified that the files I am using are the new ones.
I do:

```
swig -python -o example_wrap.c -I. -I/usr/local/include/python3.4m example.i 
cc -fPIC -I. -I/usr/local/include/python3.4m -c example.c
cc -fPIC -I. -I/usr/local/include/python3.4m -c example_wrap.c
cc -shared -o _example.so example.o example_wrap.o /usr/local/lib/libpython3.4m.a
/usr/local/bin/python3.4 -c "import example"
```

Just to be sure, instead of `cc` I tried `clang` and `gcc-mp-4.9` (from MacPorts), all with the same result.

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
```

This works perfectly fine on Linux. I don't believe I am linking against any of the Frameworks (but `python3.4` does).
What am I missing here?

Here is the code:

`example.h`

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H
extern void hello();
#endif
```

`example.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
void hello() {
   printf("Hello\n");
}
```

`example.i`

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"
```

Linking is as follows:

```
otool -L /usr/local/bin/python3.4
/usr/local/bin/python3.4:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1258.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)

otool -L _example.so 
_example.so:
    _example.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are supposed to link with:

```
cc -shared -o _example.so example.o example_wrap.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpython3.4m
```

Otherwise, some symbols from `libpython3.4m.a` may be included in your shared object, and then are available twice when importing from python (?).

In any case, on my system (OSX 10.11, with MacPorts Python 3.4), both do work.

Comment: I think you are right. My python is statically linked so symbols do get duplicated. On linux python and my shared object are dynamically linked.